# Google Sheet split cell to rows - data manipulation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-data-validation

I have a sheet, where there is a list of times in Col. C.

[image]

What I want is for it to be split into different rows & also the relevant order number & name to be copied with the rows.
Resulting look:

[image]

I have about a 300 rows of orders to do this way. Right now I'm doing it manually and its taking ages. And what I posted here is only a part of the process.

Here is the sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VENgvRAdBaAC28lpJ5a2QvD5KtnD-S3dx5rUELzvGCM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17PSp-bSOicvVvz4nCtGfNqkW9C9ZbUZkG7BvlaXd_YM/edit#gid=1415936470) Sheet "What I want".

Following formula in *I2* returns split list of items and names repeated

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 QUERY(
  SPLIT(
   FLATTEN(
    FILTER(Original!B2:B,Original!B2:B<>"")&"|"&
     SPLIT(
      IFERROR(
       REGEXREPLACE(
        FILTER(Original!C2:C,Original!C2:C<>""),"\n","&"),FILTER(Original!C2:C,Original!C2:C<>"")),"&")),
   "|"),
 "SELECT *
 WHERE Col2 <> ''"))
```

Main idea is to use [FLATTEN()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en-GB) formula to join two lists of NAME and LIST.

For NAME split we change indents to "&" using [REGEXREPLACE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en-GB) and then separate them with [SPLIT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en-GB) and [TRANSPOSE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=3105706) formulas.

QUERY() is there just to filter blanks.

In *H2* we use [SEQUENCE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en) to create IDs for all entries.

In *L2*

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER($J$2:$J,$J$2:$J<>""),"\d+")))
```

[REGEXEXTRACT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=3105625) is used to get quantity of items from LIST.

In *M2* also added VLOOKUP of ORDER NO.

Comment: thank you so much this worked! :) :)

Comment: can we adjust the formula to multiply the order number too pls, instead of adding a separate number for the ID?

Comment: Sure, added to the sheet. this part *FILTER(Original!A2:A,Original!A2:A<>"")&"|"&*

Comment: Thank you so much Oleg! :) :) :)